# AWS CloudFormation : Providing CF stack to other AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have an application developed using AWS Serverless components ( Lambda, API Gateway, DynamoDB, Cognito, etc.)

I want to deploy this application to customer's AWS Accounts.

I am thinking to create a CloudFormation stack and give the CF file to the customers. They should be able deploy the application in their AWS account by using this CF stack.

Are there any examples, pointers, best practices for this approach?

How the binaries of the lambda functions are delivered? ( S3 bucket ?)

can the ClodFormation stackSets be used for this?

Comment: The AWS Serverless Application Repository (https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/serverlessrepo/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for @Dunedan on this. CloudFormation StackSets will also work but AWS Serverless Application Repository is purposely designed for serverless.

Comment: We deliver lambda packes via an S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks. This is a useful information. I might need to use nested stacks. Is this feasible with this approach?